# College gmail account with iPhone 4S

Tags: email, gmail

I'm trying to sync my college email with my iPhone 4s. I used to have an android phone and I had the gmail setup through my college's email. It's hosted by GMAIL.

If I try now, I get invalid un/pw for imap.gmail.com.

Is there a setting that I'm missing? I have imap enabled on the gmail settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to double check - you don't have 2 step authentication on do you? After that, start over - cancel it out, and retype it in. Sometimes typos force several tries.

Comment: I don't have 2 step auth on this account.

Comment: Check this out. http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-set-up-gmail-on-ios-using-exchange-activesync. Or this for a general idea: http://google.ncsu.edu/gettingstarted/setting-ios-google-apps-nc-state

Comment: Ok, I will check that out.

Comment: Dammit, that still doesn't work. I think I might need to contact the college IT admin or something, they have a weird setup and I can't get this to work.

Comment: You could also try downloading the Gmail app from the app store just to see if it works. Otherwise, I agree, contact your IT admin.